# Strange results of `list.indexWhere` when parameter `from` is negative

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is this a bug in `indexWhere` method, or is there a meaningful explanation for the first four lines in the example bellow?

```
scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, -4)
res0: Int = -2

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, -3)
res1: Int = -1

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, -2)
res2: Int = 0

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, -1)
res3: Int = 1

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, 0)
res4: Int = 2

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, 1)
res5: Int = 2

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, 2)
res6: Int = 2

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, 3)
res7: Int = 3

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, 4)
res8: Int = 4

scala> List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhere(_ > 3, 5)
res9: Int = -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code looks like this:

```
override /*SeqLike*/
  def indexWhere(p: A => Boolean, from: Int): Int = {
    var i = from
    var these = this drop from
    while (these.nonEmpty) {
      if (p(these.head))
        return i

      i += 1
      these = these.tail
    }
    -1
  }
```

So there is no input check, neither zeroing of `i` variable. I would say it is a bug. If you can, write it on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-language where devs can take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

I think ideally you'd see an `IllegalArgumentException` if you passed a negative number as the start index (what's that supposed to mean anyway?), but maybe it was felt that the overhead of a bounds check wasn't worth it. I don't see any specified behaviour in the docs for this, so not sure I'd call it a bug; more a case of "rubbish in, rubbish out".

Comment: Well, an error would have saved me half an hour of debugging, so in my case it's definitely worth it. Alternatively, all those lines could just return 2, as that's still the correct answer - if I start counting from some imaginary negative index, values greater that 3 still start at index 2. Silently returning wrong answer is the worst of the alternatives. Although, I admit that this is definitely a case of "rubbish in".

Answer (score 0):

As a future solution, you might want to implement your own version that *does* check.  You might make it return an Option as well instead of -1, which is also unsafe:

```
implicit class WithIndexWhereSafe[T](seq: Seq[T]) { 
  def indexWhereSafe(p: T => Boolean, from: Int) = { 
    assert(from >= 0, "from must be >= 0")
    val i = seq.indexWhere(p, from) 
    if (i != -1)
      Some(i)
    else
      None
  }
}


List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhereSafe(_ > 3, 2)  // Some(2)
List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhereSafe(_ > 3, 5)  // None
List(1, 1, 4, 4, 4).indexWhereSafe(_ > 3, -4) // AssertionError
```

Comment: That's neat. However I usually avoid wrapping standard utilities, unless I really have to. And if that happens too often, then that's a clear sign that the programming language or API in question sucks. I prefer to complain until the utilities are done The Right Way™ :-)